# Ubuntu 17.04, some processes are crashing almost daily and my programs are closed unexpectedly

Tags: compiz, lock-screen, 17.04

I was using Ubuntu 16.10 with no problems at all. I was able to run some programs for days or weeks with no interruptions.

I updgraded to 17.04 recently. Now, I get some processes crashing almost daily. I am leaving my PC running overnight. When I arrive in my office next day, I get error messages from compiz or other packages and all my programs are closed.

This happens even if I wasn't running any heavy task. I have checked my uptime in htop and it is several days, so I guess this problem is not due to power interruptions and the computer didn't restart overnight.

What should I do?

Comment: Check this out: https://askubuntu.com/questions/914167/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-upgrade-full-reinstall-or-over-current-system

Comment: A clean and fresh install sounds like painful. Ok, I will try that after my next deadline...

Comment: Run the app in Terminal, see what kind of error it gives.